How to curve triangular mesh
I'm trying to make kind of a curved spike as on the reference picture under the object. I started with rectangle on the top added some loop cuts and with proportional editing set to sphere and manuvering with (G) the effect was satisfying but after I decided to sharpen the point on the top and kind of replaced rectangle with two triangles this method does not work so well. How can I round this edges.


Add some edges and push them forwards?

